# How to force CLR version in Excel 2010

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

I have a VSTO-enabled .xlt template project built in VS 2010, targeting .NET 4.0. I can install it without problems on most 64 bit Windows 7/32 bit Office 2010 systems, but am running into the error below when the .xlt is installed and opened on one 32 bit Windows 7/32 bit Office 2010 machine.

From the look of it, Excel is loading some amalgamation of .NET 2.0 & 3.5 assemblies. I've made sure to disable all other add-ins before I open the .xlt. How can I force Excel to use the .NET 4.0 CLR. Why is it loading these old assemblies?

```
************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException: Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could not be created. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'BatchUploadTemplate, Version=1.0.4024.22371, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ddd6d55be31a41' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
File name: 'BatchUploadTemplate, Version=1.0.4024.22371, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ddd6d55be31a41'
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.DomainInitializer.ActivatePipeline(String addInAssembly, String addInClass, String[] pipelineInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.DomainInitializer.StartAddIn(IntPtr hostServiceProvider, String[] pipeline, String assemblyName, String[] entryPoints)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.DomainInitializer.StartAddIn(IntPtr hostServiceProvider, String[] pipeline, String assemblyName, String[] entryPoints)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.LoadMafPipeline(AppDomain newDomain, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, String fullAssemblyName, String[] entryPoints, OfficeApp officeApplication, OfficeVersion officeVersion, IntPtr& executor)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, Boolean useFastPath, IntPtr& executor)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.31007.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5420 built by: Win7SP1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.31007.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0.dll
----------------------------------------
System.AddIn
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5446 built by: Win7SP1GDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.AddIn/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.AddIn.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.31007.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v10.0.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.30729.4130
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0/9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.31007.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5460 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5462 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Deployment
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5420 built by: Win7SP1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Without an Excel.exe.config file, the CLR version is determined by whatever addin was lucky enough to get loaded first.

Comment: Excel.exe.config is an interesting idea. I tried it locally, setting the CLR version to .NET 2.0. Strangely, my .NET 4.0 targeting .xlt still worked. I did make sure there were no other 'Active' plug-ins when I loaded the .xlt, but I don't know if 'Active' is the same as 'Loaded'

Comment: Don't try it "locally", put it in the directory that contains Excel.exe.

Comment: This is what I did. I meant on my machine rather than on the broken machine. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up re-imaging the machine in question. The template project installed without issue on atop a fresh registry and freshly installed Office 2010.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding this in your app.config, also check if you have .net 4 full framework installed on machine

```
 <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have this setting configured verbatim as you describe in app.config. Unfortunately the issue persists on the problematic machine.

Comment: what is vsto runtime installed on that machine?

Comment: I've made sure to install 4.0. There is at least one older version also installed, however.